# passing method in TabBar view in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using Tabs in flutter, here I am sending list of names(consists of unique ids) for tabs and displaying  as labels. But when I am using TabBarView, here

My requirement:
I should pass each id to method, then inside that I am calling one restApi depends on that response will change and then that response I should display under each selected tab.  Please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: I didn't get what you are doing, can u please explain more or show what you have done so far?

Comment: I am trying to call a method with grid view in tabbarview